# Exposing a Collection of Abstract Model Classes to View in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am struggling with a design desision while writing a WPF application. Here is the generic problem:

Consider an application needing to keep track of a list of abstract Vehicles that a person wants to buy. With a MVVM design, what is the best way to expose the different car types (e.g. Motorcycle, Car, Truck, etc.) to the View so that each of the Vehicle types can be shown and edited with a different form?

Currently I have this setup:

## Model

```
abstract class Vehicle { .. }
class Car : Vehicle { .. }
class Truck : Vehicle { .. }
class Cart {
    ObservableCollection<Vehicle> Vehicles;
}
```

## ViewModel

```
class VehicleViewModel { .. }
class CartViewModel {
    ObservableCollection<VehicleViewModel> Vehicles;
}
```

With this design though, I'm not sure how I can create a `DataTemplate` in my View of a Cart for each of the Vehicle types because the `CartViewModel` just contains a list of `VehicleViewModel` (and not `CartViewModel`, `TruckViewModel`, etc).

Can someone please guide me in a direction to take?

Comment: I think you're looking for [DataTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: You may also find [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview#the-datatype-property) interesting - it describes how to use `DataTemplate.DataType` property (instead of `DataTemplateSelector`) so that templates are applied automatically based on the type of the templated object.

Comment: @Grx70 I read the question in a way that he is aware of `DataType`, but in the question case, there is only one common viewmodel type for all `Vehicle` model sub-types.

Comment: @grek40 Yes, you're right, in this case I guess `DataType` is not of much use.

Comment: I would have a `List<Vehicle> Vehicles` in your `VM` and then just add appropriate elements to the collection like `Vehicles.Add(new Car());` or `Vehicles.Add(new Truck());` then in your View if you have a ListView use `DataTemplate` to differ between different types of vehicles.

Comment: Also have a `SelectedVehicle` in your `VM` and work with that, what I mean is initialise the `SelectedVehicle` property, which is of type `Vehicle`, to the type you want to create, so when you are creating a view for a car set the windows `DataContext` to `SelectedVehicle` and in your app xaml hold a `ControlTemplate` to pick up the correct datatype. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: `ObservableCollection<object>`. or whatever base class with appropriate type-based DataTemplates. No need to make it complex.